# Saving/restoring clipboard in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with many sheets.  Most sheets have some code in the Worksheet_Activate() subroutine.For some reason this code causes the contents of the clipboard to be lost - extremely annoying, as spreadsheet user cannot copy and paste between sheets.

In an attempt to fix this I have added the following lines at the beginning of the Worksheet_Activate code:

```
Dim dClipBoard As MsForms.DataObject
On Error Resume Next
Set dClipBoard = New MsForms.DataObject
dClipBoard.GetFromClipboard
```

And the following lines just before exit of the Worksheet_Activate code:

```
On Error Resume Next
dClipBoard.PutInClipboard
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  My clipboard is still lost when I move from sheet to sheet.

Comment: This has been a long-running issue which deosn't seem to have a resolution. The work-around is to advise your users to open the "Office clipboard task pane" when copying: that clipboard isn't wiped when event macros run.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine 2 different workarounds for this case.

1- If possible change the code in the worksheets. Where ever the .copy command is used replace it with codes like these:

```
range("Some Range") = range("Some other range")
```

2- If changing the code is not possible (using the approach you are currently using) instead of storing the data to an MsForms.DataObject you could copy them to some auxiliary sheet, And retrieve the data from the worksheet before the exit worksheet event triggers.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to *manual* copy-paste operations, not those performed using VBA.

Comment: Yes exactly, but the reason the manual copy paste isn't working is because somewhere in the code, the vba script is doing some copy pasting of its own.

Comment: No, that's *not* the reason.  The problem is that certain event procedures (including Worksheet_Activate) have a side-effect of clearing the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Didn't know that. Well the second method I provided is still valid

Comment: Also, setting the status bar (Appication.StatusBar = "somelthing") will clear the clipboard.